# Can't build boost 1.57 for MinGW

Tags: boost, mingw

I can't build boost 1.57 for MinGW on Win7. I tried

```
D:\boost_1_57_0>bootstrap.bat mingw
D:\boost_1_57_0>.\b2 toolset=gcc install
```

and I only got

```
D:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:1075: in configure-really
*** argument error
* rule generate-setup-cmd ( version : command : parent : options * : cpu : global-setup : default-global-setup-options : default-setup )
* called with: ( 9.0 : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC : <command>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\cl.exe : i386 :  : x86 : vcvars32.bat )
* missing argument global-setup
D:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:809:see definition of rule 'generate-setup-cmd' being called
D:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:201: in configure
D:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/tools\msvc.jam:153: in msvc.init
D:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/build\toolset.jam:43: in toolset.using
D:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src/build\project.jam:1007: in using project-config.jam:3: in modules.load
D:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:249: in load-config
D:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:412: in load-configuration-files
D:/boost_1_57_0/tools/build/src\build-system.jam:524: in load
D:\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src/kernel\modules.jam:289: in import
D:\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
D:\boost_1_57_0\boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

What is wrong?

EDIT: Now I downloaded boost 1.56 and tried the same commands and everything works fine. That's strange since I used boost on this system and after a hdd crash I have to re-build it. Everything worked fine with boost 1.57 and now I get this strange error message.

Comment: Try just D:\boost_1_57_0>.\b2 toolset=gcc

Comment: It's the same. Now I tried boost 1.58 beta and it's the same problem too.